# Show that the function is not Lebesgue Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196038/example-that-a-measurable-function-f-on-1-infty-can-be-integrable-when):

How do I show that $f(x)=\frac{(−1)^{n}}{n}$ for every $n⩽x<n+$ and $n\geq 1$ is not Lebesgue Integrable? I'm extremely confused by the notation.

What I need to show is the following: Given that $a_{n} = \int_{n}^{n+1}f$ $\forall n$, show that even though $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, $f$ is not integrable over $[1,\infty)$.

It seems to me like $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ is more of an $a_{n}$, which adds to my confusion even more.

Please help! A full solution is preferred; remember that you are talking to an extremely confused and clueless person here.

Comment: What is the definition of lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Are you sure this is the given definition of $f$?  You have written that $f$ is a function of $x$, but your definition of $f$ does not contain an $x$, which would make $f$ a constant function, hence integrable.

Comment: Is it that $|f|$ has to be lebesgue integrable? In that case it is not as the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not summable.

Comment: @timon, that's one of the qualifications. Or, you can do the thing where you show that the upper and lower Lebesgue Integral coincide.

Comment: @AegisCruiser, this is what the guy who answered the question I linked to said. It doesn't make any sense to me either. Is there a non-integrable function of $x$ that looks kind of like what he wrote that he might have meant?

Comment: @jessy cat Isn't it true if a function is lebesgue integrable then both its positive part and negative part must have to be integrable?

Comment: @timon, Yes, but part of my problem is that I don't know how to show that either part isn't integrable.

Comment: @ jessy cat did you calculate the positive part?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is Lebesgue integrable if $\int_1^\infty|f|<\infty$. Here are the graphs of $f$ and $|f|$. Can you see what's happening?

Graph of $f$

[image: Graph of f]

Graph of $|f|$

[image: Graph of |f|]

$a_n=\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}f=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum a_n$ converges. But $\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}|f|=|a_n|$ and $\sum|a_n|$ diverges.

Comment: Aguirre, it kind of looks like $|f|$ is approaching 0, but that would contradict the guy who claimed this function was not Lebesgue Integrable...

Comment: You have to show that the integral of $|f|$ diverges to $+\infty$.  That can still happen even if $|f|$ itself approaches zero.

Comment: I have completed the answer.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are talking about a family of functions dependent on a parameter:

$f_1\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^1}1,\;f_2\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-2\right)^1}2,\cdots,\;f_n\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}n,\dots$

but all this functions are integrable, I think your problem is not about a family of functions, but a one function, 
$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^1}1+\frac{\left(-2\right)^1}2+\cdots\;+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}n+\dots$
The series converges, but the function ... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The theory of integration by Lebesgue is done in several steps. Start with a general measure space $(X,\cal{B},\mu)$:

- We define integration of simple **positive** functions: If $s$ is simple and positive, it can be uniquely written as $s=\sum a_i\chi_{A_i}$, where $a_i>0$ are distinct and the $A_i$ are disjoint (here, $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$). Define $\int sd\mu=\sum_i a_i\mu(A_i)$, *which can be infinite*.
- Then we prove linearity and monotonicity of integration **for positive simple functions**.
- After this, consider any **positive** measurable map $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a sequence $(s_n)$ of simple functions such that $s_n(x)$ is increasing for all $x$ and converges to $f(x)$. Define $\int fd\mu=\sup_n\int s_nd\mu$. *Again, this can be infinite*.
- Then we need to show that the definition of $\int fd\mu$ does not depend on the given sequence $(s_n)$, and prove the usual properties of integration. ****We are still only considering positive maps**.
- Finally, we define integration for general maps. Given $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ any measurable map, we consider it's positive and negative parts $f^+=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-=\max(-f,0)$, so that $f=f^+-f^-$.

**Definition**: A function $f$ is integrable iff $\int f^+d\mu<\infty$ *and* $\int f^-d\mu<\infty$. In this case we put $\int fd\mu=\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu$.

- After this, we can finally prove the usual properties of integration (linearity, monotonicity,...)

Then we can prove the following proposition.

**Proposition**: $f$ is integrable iff $|f|$ is integrable.

All of this is basically the *definition* of what it means for a function to be (Lebesgue) integrable. Try to use the proposition above for your given function. In this case, $|f|(x)=1/n$ when $n\leq x<n+1$.

More details: Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. We will use monotone convergence. Define $g_n$ to be the restriction of $f$ to $[1,n+1)$. In this case, $g_n$ is a simple function: $g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[i,i+1)}$. By definition of integration for simple functions,
$$\int g_nd\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\lambda([i,i+1))=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$$.

Then $g_n$ is increasing and converges pointwise to $|f|$. By monotone convergence,
$$\int |f|d\lambda=\lim_n\int g_nd\lambda=\lim_n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$
so $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: the fact that it's written as a term in a sequence rather than as a function is throwing me off. I can't use the proposition to show my result because I don't know how to show that $|f|$ is integrable for this particular function. What do you do when it's in terms of $n$ instead of $x$?? I told you I was extremely confused and clueless!

Comment: Hello Kitty again.  The computational aspect of the problem is just freshman calculus.   Find your inner, more confident, undergraduate self.  Treat this as an exercise in the improper Riemann integral.  Show that $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_1^Tf(t)\,dt$ exists in that sense but $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_1^T|f(t)|\,dt$ does not.  In fact, this is the point of the exercise.  Here is a function you could integrate in a calculus class, but now in graduate school it is no longer "integrable".  You have lost the ability to integrate some functions that were no problem a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand the function definition.  It would less misleading if it were written using the floor function, specifically,
$$
f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{\lfloor x\rfloor}.
$$
If you look at the response given with the graph, you'll notice that the harmonic series is involved, which should give you the non-integrability.

Comment: does it give you the non-integrability because the harmonic series diverges? I'm guessing then that that series is the integrand?

Comment: The alternating harmonic _sequence_ is the integrand.  The integral of this is then exactly equal to the alternating harmonic series, which converges.  However, $|f|$ will be the original harmonic sequence, so its integral will be divergent.  If you refer to the posts above, you will see that this implies non-integrable.