# How to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \int_{i\pi}^{(i+1) \pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In short, I am trying to find a counterxample to Theorem 10.49b in Apostol's 'Mathematical Analysis' which is a claim that misses some assumptions related to this post: [If $a_n=\int_n^{n+1} f,$ is it true that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[1,\infty)$ if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585664/if-a-n-int-nn1-f-is-it-true-that-f-is-lebesgue-integrable-over-1-in). My candidate is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ which is not Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. To finish my counterxample I am left to prove that the series above convrges. But the only bounds I can think of are that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{i\pi}$ on $[i\pi, (i+1)\pi)$. But of course, using this bound shows that the series is bounded as $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \int_{i\pi}^{(i+1) \pi}\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi}\frac{1}{\pi} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(i+1)\pi - i\pi}{i\pi} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} \to \infty$$
which is useless. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of the alternating series test.

Define $a_i = \int\limits_{i\pi}^{(i + 1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$. Then $|a_i| = \int\limits_0^\pi \sin(x) \frac{1}{x + \pi i} dx$. Then clearly, $|a_i|$ is a decreasing sequence, since $|a_i| - |a_{i + 1}| = \int\limits_0^\pi \sin(x) (\frac{1}{x + \pi i} - \frac{1}{x + \pi(i + 1)}) dx > 0$.

And clearly, $a_i$ is an alternating sequence. And it's easy to show that $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty} a_i = 0$.

So by the alternating series test, your sum converges.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation Mark.

Comment: @DrunkPolice You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternating series with decreasing terms, so yes, it converges.