# For a bounded, measurable function $f$ defined on $[1,\infty]$, does the fact that $f$ is integrable imply that $\sum_n a_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $f$ a bounded, measurable function defined on $[1,\infty]$ and define $a_n := \int_{[n,n+1)} f$. Does the fact that $f$ is integrable imply $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

There has been [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585664/if-a-n-int-nn1-f-is-it-true-that-f-is-lebesgue-integrable-over-1-in) regarding this question but I would like to argue that the argument
\begin{equation}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n = \int^\infty_1 f
\end{equation}
made in that post is not correct.

My attempt was the following:
Since $f$ is integrable, $|f|$ is also integrable. Therefore, \begin{equation}
\int_{[1,\infty)} |f| = \lim_{k\to \infty} \int^k_1 |f| < \infty.
\end{equation}
Moreover, we have the following:
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n &= \sum^\infty_{n=1} \int^{n+1}_n f \\
&\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} |\int^{n+1}_n f| \\
&\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} \int^{n+1}_n |f| \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum^k_{n=1} \int^{n+1}_n |f| \\
\end{align}
However, I cannot proceed further from here. Can anyone help?

Comment: "Integrable" means $\int |f|<\infty$, right?

Comment: @paulgarrett I am talking about Lebesgue integration. As far as I know, yes. A function $f$ is integrable means that $\int f < \infty$. Also, a function $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: Ok, then, yes, $\int |f|<\infty$ does imply that $\int f$ exists and is finite. But/and then I don't understand why you'd think that breaking the integral of $f$ into pieces is not ok. Yes, if we make no assumptions on (absolute!) integrability of $f$, then the integrals over intervals can have self-cancellations, like $(1-1)+(1-1)+...=0$. But, depending on what you mean by "integrable", this would be assumed-away... Can you clarify?

Comment: From your comments below, perhaps there is a minor issue of "logic". Namely, yes, $\sum_n \int_n^{n+1} f$ convergent does not imply that $\int_1^\infty f$ is convergent, as your example of $\sin 2\pi x$ (or similar) illustrates. But $\sin 2\pi x$ is neither (Lebesgue) integrable, nor is it "absolutely" integrable, so it is not surprising that there's this seeming discrepancy. In the end, I'd recommend caution about use of "integrable", without "absolutely", since many Lebesgue-theory introductions allow an "integrable" non-negative-real-valued function to have integral $+\infty$...

Comment: ... AND I'd claim that there's no genuine subtlety or pathology here, just an easily-understood technicality that is mostly not the salient issue in real-life situations. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the comment. The example $\sin(2\pi x)$ is to argue that $\sum_n a_n$ converges doesn't imply that $f$ is integrable. If the equality holds, this would imply that the convergence of $\sum_n a_n$ implies the integrability of $\sin(2\pi x)$, which contradicts to the fact that $\sin(2\pi x)$ is not integrable. Therefore, I still insist that the statement that I claimed to be false is false.

Comment: @paulgarrett Also, the reasons that I don't consider breaking the integral into pieces are 1) the breaking of integrals can be easily induced based on the definition of Lebesgue integration for simple functions, but not for general functions; 2) This hasn't been proven in my course (it seems to be true from my research online, and Mason and GReyes's answers of multiplying the function with a characteristic function). I agree that we should use caution, which is why I am looking for rigorous mathematical reasoning here...

Comment: @paulgarrett ...But my example of $\sin(2\pi x)$ should be sufficient to prove that this is more than a technicality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is integrable, you know that
$$
\int\limits_1^{k+1}|f|\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\int\limits_n^{n+1}|f|\,dx
$$
converges to $\int_1^\infty |f|\,dx<\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ (by monotonic convergence, extending $f$ by zero beyond $k+1$). Thus your last limit is finite and your series $\sum a_n$ is convergent

Comment: Isn't this statement equivalent to $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n = \int^\infty_1 f$? But $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n = \int^\infty_1 f$ is not correct. A counterexample is set $f:= \sin(2\pi x)$. $a_n$ is zero for every $n$ and therefore $\sum a_n$ is zero. But $\sin(2\pi x)$ is not integrable. Assume that this statement is correct, then the fact that $\sum a_n$ converges would imply $\int f$ is integrable, which contradicts to the example I made.

Comment: No, it is not.  What we are saying is that $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent, and its sum is bounded by $\int|f|\, dx$. Therefore $\sum a_n$ is also convergent.

Comment: I get the fact that $\sum |a_n| $ is convergent, but this is what we are trying to prove. I didn't really get how you approach the statement in your answer by monotonic convergence. I assume that you meant Monotone Convergence Theorem. But this theorem requires that the sequence to be bounded. However, we are trying to prove boundedness.

Comment: Absolute convergence implies convergence. Yes, I mean Monotone convergence theorem. The theorem, for non-negative functions like $|f|$, says that the limit of the integrals is the integral of the limit.  $|f|$ is the point-wise monotonic limit of its restrictions to $[1,n+1)$. Your limit is integrable, so it it finite.

Comment: I still don't get which sequence of functions we are applying MCT to. Is it the sequence of functions $\{\sum_{n=1}^k \int_n^{n+1} |f| \}_k$? This gives $\lim_{k\to\infty}( \sum_{n=1}^k \int_n^{n+1} |f|  )= \int_n^{n+1}( \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k  |f| )$. I cannot see how the right hand side of the equality is $\int_1^\infty |f|$.

Comment: Observe that $\sum_{n=1}^k\int_{n}^{n+1}|f|dx=\int_1^{k+1}|f|dx$. We apply MCT to the sequence $g_k(x)=|f|\chi_{[1,k+1)}(x)$. Clearly, $g_k$ approaches monotonically to $|f|$. Therefore, $\int g_k(x)\,dx\to\int|f|\,dx<\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|a_n| &\leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{[n, n + 1)}|f| \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int |f| 1_{[n, n + 1)} \\
&= \int \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|f| 1_{[n, n + 1)} \\
&= \int |f|1_{[1, \infty)} \\
&< \infty.
\end{align}
The second equality is by MCT and additivity of the integral on nonnegative functions. Alternatively, you can argue directly using DCT that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n = \int f1_{[1, \infty)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I do think that a substantial part of the issue here is terminological, or similar. But not a mysterious mathematical issue (beyond a standard sort of example).

Namely, first, indeed, convergence, or even absolute convergence, of the *series* $\sum_n \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\;dx$ proves nothing about *any* sort of convergence or integrability or absolute integrability of $f$. The example of $f(x)=\sin 2\pi x$ illustrates this, and it's not a pathology, etc.

On another hand, equally robustly, if "$f$ integrable" means *absolutely* integrable, then by various means $\int_1^\infty f = \sum_n \int_n^{n+1} f$.

If real-valued $f$ is "integrable" in a technical Lebesgue-theory sense, namely, that one or the other of its positive and negative parts is absolutely integrable, while the other may fail to be so... we still reach the conclusion.

If there are other contexts of interest to the questioner, I'd be happy to entertain them. But, beyond the basic counter-example to a too-naive appraisal of the situation, I do not think there's a pathology here.